# Why is tls.Client failing with message:first record does not look like a TLS handshake

Tags: go, ssl, tls1.2

I'm trying to run the buildlet at https://github.com/golang/build/tree/master/cmd/coordinator

There is a locally hosted server connection that keeps failing to connect giving the error:

```
first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

The piece of code that fails is from build/cmd/buildlet/reverse.go and it is:

```
    tcpConn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(30 * time.Second))
    config := &tls.Config{
        ServerName:         serverName,
        InsecureSkipVerify: devMode,
    }
    conn := tls.Client(tcpConn, config)
    if err := conn.Handshake(); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to handshake with coordinator: %v", err)
    }
```

I've gathered that the connection should be established while ignoring TLS issues because the server is at localhost

I can't seem to figure out how to fix this issue.
Instructions on recreating my problem are at the above link. The only change I recommend is using

```
go run . -mode=dev -listen-http=localhost:8119
```

for the first command

Comment: Looks like you are trying to create a TLS connection while the server does not speak TLS. Note that `-listen-http=localhost:8119` means plain HTTP, not HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

`InsecureSkipVerify` just means that TLS certificate validation constraints are relaxed (to a point where your connection is insecure and prone to MITM attacks)

From the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Config):

> If InsecureSkipVerify is true, crypto/tls accepts any certificate presented by the server and any host name in that certificate.

You still need to have a connection that uses TLS at the other end. The error that you're getting means that the other side of the connect doesn't speak TLS.

If you don't want to use TLS in devMode, then you should use the `tcpConn` directly while in dev mode, without wrapping it with a `*tls.Conn`. `*tls.Conn` implements `net.Conn` so after the handshake there shouldn't be any difference in how you use the connection, whether it has TLS or not.